# How to retrieve notification information using SharePoint webhooks

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, webhooks

I am working on SharePoint webhooks. I have performed the steps of [Get started with SharePoint webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks) and I am getting output like following:

```
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Resource: c34420f9-2a67-4e54-94c9-b6770892299b'
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='SubscriptionId: 32b95ad9-4d20-4a17-bfa3-2957cb38ead8'
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='TenantId: 7a17cb7d-6898-423f-8839-45f363076f06'
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='SiteUrl: /'
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='WebId: 62b80e0b-f889-4974-a519-cc138413be40'
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='ExpirationDateTime: 2016-10-27T16:17:57.0000000Z'
```

It is very difficult to understand which operation has performed using above data.
How can I retrieve the notification information like performed operation name (Example: Deleted, updated and added)?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint only sends a notification that a change happened, but the notification does not include what actually changed.

To understand what was changed, you'll need to use the SharePoint `GetChanges()` API.

See this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/webhooks-reference-implementation#grab-the-changes-your-service-needs-to-act-upon).

Based on [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433%28v%3Doffice.15%29#getchanges-method) of `GetChanges()` API, the request url should be like:

```
<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists(guid'51925dd7-2108-481a-b1ef-4bfa4e69d48b')/getchanges?@target='<host web url>
```

Comment: how can I use this API and where?

Comment: @AbhiSingh I have provided the sample in my answer: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/blob/master/Samples/WebHooks.List/SharePoint.WebHooks.Common/ChangeManager.cs#L99. You should modify the code based on your needs and add it to your SPWebhookController: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks#build-sharepoint-webhook-controller.

Comment: I tried to use this code before but it was giving me error **"Could not load file or assembly 'OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.6.1608.0. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."**

Comment: Do you know what is the URL that is exactly formed to retrieve the changes received in the Webhook?